# Use same jenkinsfile for different global timeout options

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I have a situation where i have to run same pipeline (set of stages) daily and weekly. But the catch is timeout option.

- For nightly build, we have strict timeout of 4 hours
- For Weekly build, we have timeout of 48 hours (as retrying some stages in pipeline multiple times)
- We can differentiate build using BUILD_TAGS, but stuck with global timeout option.
- Don't want to go with stage timeout option, as it calculates even waiting for node time.

> ```
> pipeline {
>     agent any
>     options {
>         // Timeout counter starts AFTER agent is allocated
>         timeout(time: 4, unit: 'HOURS')
>     }
>     stages {
>         stage('Build') {
>             steps {
>                 echo 'Hello World'
>             }
>         }
>         stage('Test') {
>             steps {
>                 echo 'Hello World'
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Have anyone tried similar scenario? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you can figure out why your job is running — namely, is it a weekly or nightly (or none of these) — this becomes fairly easy.

This solution includes ParameterizedCron plugin to pass the reason as parameter:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'IS_NIGHTLY', defaultValue: false)
        booleanParam(name: 'IS_WEEKLY', defaultValue: false)
    }
    triggers {
        parameterizedCron("H 1 * * 1-7 % IS_NIGHTLY=true")
        parameterizedCron("H 1 * * 6 % IS_WEEKLY=true")
    }
    options {
        // Once you have indication of why your build is running:
        timeout(time: IS_NIGHTLY ? 4 : (IS_WEEKLY ? 48 : 1), unit: 'HOURS')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution would include running a little code before pipeline starts to dig in `BuildCauses`:

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field
TIMEOUT = 4
try {
    if (currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0].shortDescription.contains("timer")) {
        TIMEOUT = 48 // deciphering between nightly and weekly left as excercise
    }
} catch (error) {
    echo error.getMessage()
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        // Timeout counter starts AFTER agent is allocated
        timeout(time: TIMEOUT, unit: 'HOURS')
// etc.
```